# Error 403 al hacer una petición de datos json a una url para deserializar con gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Estoy haciendo pruebas para convertir los datos json que devuelve una url a algo que pueda usar de alguna manera en java, como por ejemplo a objetos. Para ello estoy usando la librería gson. Este ejemplo que encontrado en teoría debe funcionar, pero al ejecutarlo me da el error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

y dice que está causado por:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://freemusicarchive.org/api/get/albums.json?api_key=60BLHNQCAOUFPIBZ&limit=5
```

En la linea que contiene:

```
String json = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
```

Si no tengo entendido mal, el error 403 es que el servidor ha recibido mi petición pero me deniega los datos.

¿Como podría solucionar esto?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class gsonexample {

    public gsonexample() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url = "http://freemusicarchive.org/api/get/albums.json?api_key=60BLHNQCAOUFPIBZ&limit=5";
        String json = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        // The JsonElement is the root node. It can be an object, array, null or
        // java primitive.
        JsonElement element = parser.parse(json);
        // use the isxxx methods to find out the type of jsonelement. In our
        // example we know that the root object is the Albums object and
        // contains an array of dataset objects
        if (element.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject albums = element.getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(albums.get("title").getAsString());
            JsonArray datasets = albums.getAsJsonArray("dataset");
            for (int i = 0; i < datasets.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject dataset = datasets.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println(dataset.get("album_title").getAsString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

La salida da:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://freemusicarchive.org/api/get/albums.json?api_key=60BLHNQCAOUFPIBZ&limit=5
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1153)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1140)
    at gestor.de.colecciones.gsonexample.<init>(gsonexample.java:24)
    at gestor.de.colecciones.main.main(main.java:62)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application gestor.de.colecciones.main
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

a mi me paso algo similar y era por el protocolo.

Estaba intentando acceder a un sitio con `http` y falla por que necesita conexion segura, `https`

Comment: Nada. Añado la pruebo con la url como https y pasa lo mismo. Además, la url que use es irrelevante, siempre da el mismo fallo.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/52181)

Comment: @toledano técnicamente, es una respuesta válida. Muy corta, que puede mejorar más, pero es una respuesta y no un comentario.

Answer (score -3):

Me sucedio algo similar al desarrollar sobre [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), pero compile el mismo codigo sobre [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) y funciono correctamente.

Por si a alguien le sirve una opcion es cambiar de version de java.

Comment: _"Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL"_ El error es claro, básicamente el usuario no estaba autorizado a realizar la petición. No tiene nada que ver con la versión de java.

Comment: Te cuento que en mi caso particular si tiene que ver con la versión de java, el servidor rechaza la petición cuando la ejecuto con un jar compilado en java 8 acá todo meda 403 pero si compilo el mismo código en java 11 me da 200

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/339025)

Comment: Posiblemente esté relacionado, pero esto seguro obedece a una configuración y no a la versión de Java que compila el código. Seguro hay una opción _menos nuclear_ que cambiar un proyecto a Java 11